# immutable Chai Assertion error while expected equals result

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, chai, chai-immutable

I have been using node/redux and i have the following while testing with chai :

```
AssertionError: expected 'Map { "winos": List [ Map { "id": 1, "x": 1, "y": 1, "movable": false }, Map { "id": 2, "x": 2, "y": 2, "movable": false }, Map { "id": 5, "x": 5, "y": 5, "movable": false } ] }'
                to equal 'Map { "winos": List [ Map { "id": 1, "x": 1, "y": 1, "movable": false }, Map { "id": 2, "x": 2, "y": 2, "movable": false }, Map { "id": 5, "x": 5, "y": 5, "movable": false } ] }'
```

I have seen that this is a known error : https://github.com/astorije/chai-immutable/issues/24.
The person there managed to solve this by making everything in the tree immutable, but i think i already have everything immutable.

My code is below :

```
import {List, Map} from 'immutable';
import {expect} from 'chai';

export function addWino(state, wino) {
    return state.updateIn(['winos'], arr => arr.push(wino));
}

describe('setWinos', () => {
describe('addWino', () => {
    it('adds a Wino', () => {

      const wino = Map({
        id: 5,
        x:5,
        y:5,
        movable: false
      });

      const nextState = addWino(state, wino);
      expect(nextState).to.equal(Map({
        winos: List.of([
          Map({
            id: 1,
            x:1,
            y:1,
            movable: false
          })
        ],
        [
          Map({
            id: 2,
            x:2,
            y:2,
            movable: false
          })
        ],
        [
          Map({
            id: 5,
            x:5,
            y:5,
            movable: false
          })
        ])
      }));

    });
  });
}
```

I also have already tried `.eql()` and `.to.deep.equal()`.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found why, instead of :

```
winos: List.of([
      Map({
        id: 1,
        x:1,
        y:1,
        movable: false
      })
    ],
    [
      Map({
        id: 5,
        x:5,
        y:5,
        movable: false
      })
    ])
  }));
```

i should have :

```
winos: List.of(
      Map({
        id: 1,
        x:1,
        y:1,
        movable: false
      }),
      Map({
        id: 5,
        x:5,
        y:5,
        movable: false
      })
    )
  }));
```

The `[]` where not needed and creating an additionnal list.

Comment: You should mark this answer as resolving your question, since this was indeed the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your assertion is of the wrong type. assert.equal (and similar) usually test if two things are "the same". in case of objects, this holds not true if its not exactly the same object. even if the content is the same. Look for something like "deepEqual" for your assertion framework

see here: https://tonicdev.com/lipp/deep-equal

```
var assert = require('assert')

var x = {a: 123}
var y = x
assert.equal(x, y)

var u = {a: 123}
assert.deepEqual(x, u, 'this is ok')
assert.equal(x, u, 'this fails')
```

Comment: I already tried it but i get the same output. I added it to the main post. Thanks anyways.

Comment: sorry this did not help you.